# Using Nanoc with Bower and CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, bower, nanoc

I had to use the `static` datasource for **Bower** packages because **Nanoc** (`filesystem_unified`
 datasource) does not allow multiple files with same filename and different extension.

But the static datasource treats each item as binary and does not allow me to apply `filters`, so I can not apply a filter for .coffee files in order to compile to .js

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It lets you apply filters, but not text filters, since all static data source items are "binary".

Nanoc 4 is fixing a whole mess of things like this, but you probably need a fix sooner than that :)

The easiest fix for you would be to drop a copy of the static data source in your `lib` directory, change the name/class to be something unique, switch the item type to text, and use that version instead.